# Any good reason why Lookup<TKey, TElement> class have no public constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Why there is no public constructor in `System.Linq.Lookup<TKey, TElement>` class ?

What was intention of .net framework designer to make `Lookup` constructor private ?

Comment: What do you need a constructor for that you can't do with `ToLookup`?  The class is immutable so all you could do is create an empty lookup.

Comment: My intention was to use Lookup class as dictionary, to add elements as needed.

Comment: `Lookup` has no mechanism to add items, so you'd be stuck there too.  Why not just use a `Dictionary` in the first place?

Comment: @MarkoKrizmanic Then use `Dictionary`, not `Lookup`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't read the minds of the .NET developers.

Comment: @Servy In my scenario I can't use 'Dictionary' because it does not allow multiple keys.

Comment: @MarkoKrizmanic Then you should do some research in how to get a dictionary that can have multiple keys (as there is plenty of information out there on how to accomplish this), rather than asking why `Lookup` doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: I got my answer, "because it is immutable". But it would be good to have mutable 'Lookup' class in .net framework, like Dictionary.

Comment: @MarkoKrizmanic Same argument - you can do something similar with `Dictionary<Tkey,List<Tvalue>>` with [some extra work when adding an item](https://code.google.com/p/edulinq/source/browse/src/Edulinq/Lookup.cs).  Is the value worth the expense?

Comment: @DStanley In 'Dictionary' I can't add multiple 'TKey' values.

Comment: @MarkoKrizmanic You can't in `Lookup` either - it's one key mapped to _multiple_ values.

Comment: @DStanley, Yes you can map multiple keys to multiple values in 'Lookup'.

Comment: @MarkoKrizmanic the lookup that is generated has unique keys that each can map to multiple values.

Comment: @DStanle ok, that way you are right, I understand now. Thank you for giving detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two *possible* reasons:

1. Because it is immutable, so all initialization must be done at construction, therefore a factory method (`Enumerable.ToLookup`) is more appropriate in this case than a complex public constructor.
2. Because the factory method is sufficient to create a `Lookup`, no constructor is necessary.

In the end, the designers don't have to justify *not* doing something.  I can see little value of a constructor when a factory method exists to create one.  If you feel that there is a use case where the *value* of a constructor outweighs the *cost* of adding one (including designing, building, testing, documenting, and supporting), then feel free to make a suggestion on http://connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: The first argument isn't valid in my opinion, there are plenty of classes with public constructors that are immutable.  The two concepts are orthogonal.

Comment: @Matthen yes but in that case the _constructor_ has to have all information necessary to create the class. A factory method is more practical in this case since it would be able to mutate the object privately (or internally in this case).

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for the clarification.